# How to render cshtml page in angular 2/4 application

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I used [controllerName]/[actionname] in the template url but I got error in the console.

Here is the screenshot of the code.

[image]

Comment: If you want our help, you better give us more clue what and how you did

Comment: Please read, [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is very unclear in what\how you are trying to achieve, what is the error.

Comment: I updated my question and also provided the screenshot of the code that i used.